# Alterar campo unique collection mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Bom dia,

Tenho uma *collection* no *mongodb* com um campo `unique:true`.

Gostaria de alterar para false este campo.

Se eu alterar o codigo e deletar toda collection funciona, mas se eu fizer a alteração no codigo e não apagar a *collection* ele não aceita.

Meu schema esta assim:

```
var chamadosSchema = new Schema({
    CODIGO_CONTRATO:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    CODIGO_IMOVEL:{type:String, default:'', unique:true, required:true},
    ENDERECO:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    BAIRRO:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    PRIORIDADE:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    NOME_PROPRIETARIO:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    DDD_PROPRIETARIO:{type:String, default:''},
    TEL_RESIDENCIAL_PROPRIETARIO:{type:String, default:''},
    TEL_CELULAR_PROPRIETARIO:{type:String, default:''},
    TEL_COMERCIAL_PROPRIETARIO:{type:String, default:''},
    E_MAIL_PROPRIETARIO:{type:String, default:''},
    SOLICITANTE:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    TEL_RESIDENCIAL_SOLICITANTE:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    TEL_COMERCIAL_SOLICITANTE:{type:String, default:''},
    EMAIL_SOLICITANTE:{type:String, default:''},
    RP_CHAMADO:{type:String, default:'', required:true},
    DATA_CHAMADO:{type:Date, default:'', required:true},
    SOLICITACAO:{type:String, default:'', required:true}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é o caso de rodar [`db.collection.dropIndex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-indexes/#remove-a-specific-index). Quando você cria esse model com o `mongoose`, ele registra sua collection e a configura para indexar os campos marcados como `unique`. Você pode ler mais sobre como isso funciona no nível do MongoDB [aqui](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#create-a-unique-index).

A solução no seu caso é simples: rode `db.nomeDaCollection.dropIndex({ nomeDoCampo: 1 })` no REPL do mongo (rodando `mongo` para conectar na sua instância e `use nomeDoSeuBanco` para o configurar para usar o seu banco de dados.

Nesse caso, imagino que sua collection se chame `chamados`, portanto:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: test
> db.chamados.dropIndex({ CODIGO_IMOVEL: 1 })
{ “nIndexesWas”: algum número, “ok”: 1 }
>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado yamadapc, deu certo.

Comment: Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta se seu problema foi resolvido :)